# Unable to find locators for App Login - Xamarin.UI Automation test

Tags: xamarin, mobile, ios-ui-automation

As our app login page is upgraded from ADAL library to MSAL library. We are unable to find the locators(Automation IDs) for sign in option via Automation.

we tried

```
App.EnterText(“UserID”);
App.PressEnter();
App.EnterText(“Password”);
App.PressEnter();
```

but the value is not entering in user name field and got below Exception Exception: System.Exception: No keyboard is visible for text entry.
at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSApp+<>c__DisplayClass19_0.b__0 () [0x0002b] in <5c98084b260c4b7c9bafd9f653301be5>:0

Any suggestions to identify the user name field.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Xamarin.UITest to the Xamarin.Forms solution first.

And Set the `AutomationId`for the Entry.

xaml:

```
 <Entry AutomationId="UserID" />
        <Entry AutomationId="Password" />
```

UITest:

```
 [Test]
    public void test3()
    {

        app.EnterText("UserID","5");//UserID is 5
        app.PressEnter();
        app.EnterText("Password","123456");//password is 123456
        app.PressEnter();

    }
```

Comment: The screen is loaded as webpage from Microsoft AD. We dont have control on it